# io.TextIOWrapper back instead of text when using file.open

Tags: python, encoding

New to Python, so I'm sure this question has a painfully obvious answer but I can't find it.

I'm writing a webscraper. I get perfect HTML back when I read a file live, like this:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
        headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 
        request=urllib.request.Request(URL,None,headers)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        page_data = response.read()
```

But if I save that HTML locally and try to open it with file.open, I get back **<_io.TextIOWrapper name='metacritic_main_html/0.html' mode='r' encoding='US-ASCII'>** instead of the HTML. I've checked the file itself and the HTML is perfectly intact which makes me thing I'm doing something dumb in reading it back.

Here's that code:

```
files = os.listdir(file_dir)

for f in files:
    file_loc = file_dir + f
    print(file_loc)

    with open(file_loc) as html:
        print(html)
```

The output of that last print statement is <_io.TextIOWrapper name='metacritic_main_html/0.html' mode='r' encoding='US-ASCII'>
, not the HTML as I'd expect.

What am I missing? I've successfully opened files before when the path is more explicit.

Comment: You never read the file. Calling a variable `html` does not mean it will magically contain the HTML stored in the file.

Comment: Of course, I didn't think it did, I was just being contextual. How would I go about actually reading the content of the file, then?

Comment: The `html` variable contain the `io.TextIOWrapper` (which is the opened file). To read the file use `html.read()`. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.read).

Comment: Hooboy. Thanks @JohnAnderson - I was previously using an HTML Parser that handled that bit for me. Fixed!